# JAGS: Invalid vector argument to ilogit

Tags: jags

I am trying to run the following model.  It has several logit links in it, which are in loops.

```
model {
for(i in 1:8){
 year.eff[i] ~ dnorm(0,tau.yr) 
 annual.controlrenest[i] <- pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]+beta.renest),37)
 annual.treatmentrenest[i] <- 
 pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]+beta.treatment+beta.renest),37)
 annual.controlnest[i] <- pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]),37)
 annual.treatmentnest[i] <- pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]+beta.treatment),37)
 annual.controlrenest[i] <- pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]+beta.renest),37)
 annual.treatmentrenest[i] <- 
 pow(ilogit(beta0+year.eff[i]+beta.treatment+beta.renest),37)
}

# Likelihood
for(i in 1:539){
  for(j in (enter.nest[i]+1):left.nest[i]){
    logit(phinest[i,j]) <- beta0 + year.eff*year.nest[i] + 
    beta.treatment*Treatment[i] + beta.renest*Renest[i]
    mu[i,j] <- phinest[i,j] * n[i,j-1]
    n[i,j] ~ dbern(mu[i,j]) 
  }
 }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error and can't seem to figure out where the issue is.  I have gotten this error before when my logit link wasn't in a loop (you can't vectorize a logit link in JAGS).

```
   Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
   3 nodes produced errors; first error: RUNTIME ERROR:
   Invalid vector argument to ilogit
```

Comment: `ilogit` can only take scalars (no vectors). As the code you provided only includes priors for `year.eff` there is no way to tell where you have provided a vector to `ilogit`. You have to index all vectors (as you did with `year.eff[i]` in the top part of your model.